# Use bash to concatenate a list of items

Tags: list, concatenation

I have a list of items like:

```
ERR001268_chr6  
ERR001312_chr6  
ERR001332_chr6  
ERR001361_chr6
ERR001369_chr6  
ERR001413_chr6  
ERR001433_chr6 
ERR001462_chr6  
ERR001698_chr6  
ERR001734_chr6  
ERR001763_chr6
ERR001774_chr6  
ERR001799_chr6
```

say now I want to concatenate ERR001268_chr6 until ERR001763_chr6.
I can do `cat ERR001268_chr6 ERR001269_chr6....ERR001763_chr6 > xxx`
But obviously I don't want to type in these items one by one...So any simple bash commands to do this?
thx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the item list is the full list of 'files' under current directory:

```
cat `ls -1 ERR*_chr6 | head -n11` > xxx
```

Comment: I'm guessing he probably doesn't need the `head -n11`. At first I was confused why you were using `-n11` instead of `-n13` but I see you caught he only had the first 11 in his example.  I think that was only an example, but either way you perfectly answered the question so upvote =)

Comment: yes, I'm assuming that he want the first 11 items out of the list, as there is not other hints on the selection criteria..